# Как сделать движущийся текст в ComboBox/TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

нужно сделать так, чтобы текст двигался слева направо, плавно. Не знаю, думаю многие видели этот эффект, пример не могу найти, как бы смешно не звучало... То есть, если текст не влез - то текст двигается в textbox'e. Не знаю, поймет ли меня кто-то, но надеюсь, что да.

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - это перевести строку в массив симоволов и свапать элементы друг с другом. А между итерациями вставлять Thread.Sleep(). Ну и все это в другом потоке, соотвественно.

Comment: `TextBox` предназначен для редактирования текста. Может `Label`?

Comment: Извините, перепутал вообще. ComboBox, там выпадающий список, и он меняется, если выбрать и не влезает - то нужно делать так, чтобы оно шло вправо.

Comment: Не пишите важную информацию в комментариях. Редактируйте вопрос!

Comment: Всё страньше и страньше... А видео со звуком воспроизводить не надо? Вы уж определитесь изначально с требованиями.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, просто перепутал TextBox с ComboBox'ом, нужно чтобы текст в ComboBox'е шел плавно вправо, если он не влез. То есть весь текст остается в ComboBox'e, а текст, который не влез, чтобы было понятно, что там написано, не выделяя его - сам двигался вправо. (плавно)

Comment: Я бы просто добавил ToolTip к комбобоксу, в котором показывал бы длинный текст. То есть пользователь навёл мышку - получил тултип.

Comment: Я вспомнил! Это называется бегущая полоса, как в новостях! Вот! Это реально реализовать и как?

Comment: @0day. на стандартном контроле - никак, не предназначен он для этого. Про `ToolTip` вам уже сказали. Стоит ли заморачиваться с кастомным контролом - не знаю, руками сделать-то можно все, ну рано или поздно, но надо ли оно вам с учетом времени и объема работы на отладку и тонкую настройку такого контрола...